# Unwrap variable if it's a swift Optional?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to determine if a variable of type `Any` is an optional, and if it is I need to unwrap it. Is this possible? this code explains what I'm trying to achieve. I understand that Optional is generic and the way I have it coded is not gonna work, wondering if there is a workaround

```
extension Serializable {
    public func serialize() -> [String: Any] {
        var result = [String: Any]()
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        for child in mirror.children {
            guard let label = child.label else { continue }

            if let optional = child.value as? Optional {
                if case Optional.some(let value) = optional {
                    result[label] = value
                }
            }
            else {
                result[label] = child.value
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work

```
extension Serializable {
    public func serialize() -> [String: Any] {
        var result = [String: Any]()
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)

        for child in mirror.children {
            guard let label = child.label else { continue }

            switch child.value {
            case let serializable as Serializable:
                result[label] = serializable.serialize()

            case let optional as Optional<Any>:
                if case .some(let value) = optional {
                    result[label] = value
                }

            default:
                result[label] = child.value
            }
        }

        return result
    }
}
```